# IE ActiveX change User Agent to Mobile

Tags: internet-explorer, registry, activex

I am using some software which uses the IE ActiveX as browser.

What I need it so do it make it browse which a mobile user agent.

I've been looking into the registry but I cannot find how I could set/change to user agent in the IE ActiveX control.

Do anyone have any idea on how to so this or if it can be done at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your application uses the IE ActiveX, a dependency exists between your EXE and the ActiveX component (which is actually "just" a DLL). This dependency cannot be changed using the registry. The Windows loader normally resolves these dependencies using Import Address Table (IAT) and the Exported Address Table (EAT) of the client (your app) and server (IE ActiveX component) - when the components are statically bound - and NOT any registry settings.

Should you want a more flexible solution, the binding between your app and the browser must be dynamically implemented by your app.